# Show /hide table rows but

Tags: html-table, row, hide, show

If someone can help:
Try to hide/show some rows in a HTML table, setting the style `display:none` or `display:block`
attributes in some table rows.
The problem is that if I set the `display:block`, seems to every data in one column, the expanded rows are lost the width of the table cells.

It is currently Firefox browser.

The toggle script is:

```
<script language="javascript">
  function toggle_it(itemID){   
  // Toggle visibility between none and inline
 var Nondisp = document.getElementsByClassName(itemID) 
 for( var i=0; i < Nondisp.length ; i++) 
{
  if ((Nondisp[i].style.display == 'none'))   
    {                                                              
     Nondisp[i].style.display = 'block';     
      } else {                                                     
      Nondisp[i].style.display = 'none';      
      }                                                            
  }                                                                
  }                                                                
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the difference between `Display:None` and `Visibility:Hidden` at: [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Setting visibility to hidden should still allocate the room in your table where your current setting of display:none completely removes the item from layout considerations.

Comment: Hi Thank you with visibility:collapse and visible working as I wanted , Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Use `table-row` instead of `block`.